# How can change disabled style for select box with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the second's select box disabled style when the first select box is changed but I can't. Please help me.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select onchange="a()" id="1">
            <option>Choose</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
        <select id="2" disabled="true">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function a(){
                if(document.getElementById('1').value!="Choose"){
                    document.getElementById('2').style.background="yellow";
                    document.getElementById('2').style.disabled="false";
                }
            }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Donte'Trumble You shouldn't need a Fiddle for something as simple as this ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I deleted it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`disabled` is a property of the element, NOT its style collection.

```
document.getElementById('2').disabled = false;
```

It is also important to note that `1` and `2` are NOT valid IDs in HTML older than HTML5, which means older browser may have severe issues with it (such as not recognising it as an ID, not finding it with `getElementById`, not styling it, etc.) I suggest giving meaningful IDs, even if it's just `select1` and `select2`, that helps reduce the chance of accidentally duplicating IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The "disabled" part is an attribute of the select element, not a CSS property.

Try this instead :

```
document.getElementById('2').disabled=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` is an attribute, not style property. That should do:

```
function a(){
    if(document.getElementById('1').value!="Choose"){
        document.getElementById('2').style.background = "yellow";
        document.getElementById('2').disabled = false;
    }
}
```